# Два блока <div> рядом в HTML в Qt 5.5

Tags: html, qt, qt5

Использую метод `setHtml()` класса `QTextDocument`. Хочу, чтобы 2 блока отрисовывались рядом. Для браузеров гуглится следующий код:

```
<div style="width:100%;"> 
    <div style="float:left;">Content left div</div> 
    <div style="float:right;">Content right div</div> 
</div>
```

при отрисовке в Qt блоки находятся друг под другом. В документации сказано, что тэг `float` работает только для таблиц и изображений.

Как два блока `<div>` разместить рядом в HTML Qt5?

Comment: Скорей всего — (разумными средствами) ни как. Qt поддерживает крайне ограниченное подмножество html.

Comment: Ничего не знаю про Qt, но для выстраивания блоков, имхо, лучше всего использовать flexbox: https://html5.by/blog/flexbox/ Если вы можете любой произвольный стиль вписать в атрибут `style`, делайте через flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Добавить значение ширины для первого блока в 50%:

```
<div style="width:100%;"> 
    <div style="float:left; width: 50%">Content left div</div> 
    <div style="float:right;">Content right div</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: ничего не поменялось